# Upload video MP4 on Instagram

Tags: video, upload, instagram, mp4

I have a MP4 video of a one of my project and I would like to share it on my Instagram profile. The video is 18s length, its size is 9.4Mo, the frame is set to 30/s and the resolution is really less than 1000px width.

I read a lot about the specifications that file must have. And it seems ok to me... Did anyone already have this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was an error when exporting the file, the video couldn't be read by any player.